# Create row level trigger for Partitioned table

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds-aurora

I have created a partitioned table (`base`), and an audit table for it(`base_audit`) and then created child tables (`c1,c2,c3,..cn`). To populate entries in `base_audit`, I have created a function and a row level trigger as below.

```
--Initial tables and partitions
create table base(id bigint, val text) partition by range (id);
create table base_audit(id bigint, val text, act char);
create table c1 partition of base for values from (1) to (3);
create table c2 partition of base for values from (4) to (6);
create table c3 partition of base for values from (7) to (10);

--Trigger function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION base_function() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
if (tg_op = 'UPDATE') then
    if (old.id = new.id) then
        insert into base_audit values (old.id, oid.val, 'u');
        return new;
    else
        insert into base_audit values (old.id, oid.val, 'i');
        insert into base_audit values (new.id, new.val, 'a');
        return new;
    end if;
    elseif (tg_op = 'DELETE') then
        insert into base_audit values (old.id, oid.val, 'd');
        return old;
    end if;
    return new;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

--Trigger
CREATE TRIGGER base_trigger BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON base FOR EACH row EXECUTE PROCEDURE base_function();
```

When I try to run the above create trigger sql, I am getting the below exception

```
ERROR:  "base" is a partitioned table
DETAIL:  Partitioned tables cannot have ROW triggers.
SQL state: 42809
```

I couldn't get what I am missing here. Is it something to do with Aurora Postgresql?

(Using Aurora Postgresql 10.7)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Aurora, but on recent PostgreSQL your trigger will work just fine if you define it to fire `AFTER` rather than `BEFORE` the DML operation. That should work just as well.

Triggers on partitioned tables were introduced in v11 - is upgrading an option?

Comment: Though I am trying to create a ```AFTER``` trigger, I am getting the same exception.

Comment: I checked, and triggers on partitioned tables were added in v11.

Comment: I don't have any upgrading plan for now. If there is no other option, I should prepare for one.

Comment: Seems, Postgresql doesn't allow to create row level trigger on the base (logical) table. I have to create the triggers on each child tables.

Comment: Just use an `AFTER` trigger like I said in my answer, then it will work (in v11).